# Trying to add a new attribute in <amp-ad>

Tags: ampscript, amp-ad

I am trying to add a new attribute in amp-ad using amp-script but it's getting sanitized as you can check console warning.

[Code](https://playground.amp.dev/?_gl=1*15lid0v*_ga*YW1wLW1YYklkc3ZMNDd2V0RoT0ZBSzlweWc.&runtime=amphtml#share=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)

Expected: A new attribute being added to amp-ad namely x having value '1234'